# Core data fetching object only once (for the same context)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a qrcode scan feature in my app, and every time I do a scan, I must save a scan record that belongs to an Event (another entity). So I fetch the event and set as attribute of the scan.

The problem is: only the first scan saved have the Event relation properly set, the following scans end all without the event.

Here's my current architecture:
ViewController -> Service -> Persistence Service -> NSManagedObject

All my classes in Persistence Service layer are child of the following class:

```
# PersistenceService.h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface PersistenceService : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *context;

-(instancetype) init;
-(void) saveContext;
@end

# PersistenceService.m
@implementation PersistenceService

-(instancetype) init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.context = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
        self.context.parentContext = [DataManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;
    }

    return self;
}

-(void) saveContext {
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.context.parentContext;

    [self.context performBlock:^{

        NSError *error;
        [self.context save:&error];

        [context performBlock:^{
            NSError *error;
            [context save:&error];

            [context.parentContext performBlock:^{
                NSError *error;
                [context.parentContext save:&error];

            }];
        }];
    }];

}

@end
```

So this is how I save my Scan:

```
# PseudoLeadPersistenceService.m
-(void) saveOrUpdatePseudoLead:(Lead *)lead ofType:(PseudoLeadType)type {
    PseudoLeadDAO *pseudoLeadDAO = [PseudoLeadDAO findPseudoLeadByCode:lead.qrcode.code andEventId:lead.event.idEvent inContext:self.context];
    if (pseudoLeadDAO == nil) {
        pseudoLeadDAO = [[PseudoLeadDAO alloc] initWithLead:lead andType:type andContext:self.context];
    } else {
        [pseudoLeadDAO setAttributesWithLead:lead];
    }
    [self saveContext];
}
```

And here I set the event in the PseudoLeadDAO (I hate this class name):

```
# PseudoLeadDAO.m
-(void) setAttributesWithLead:(Lead *)lead {
    [self setPseudoLeadID:lead.id];
    [self setHotlead:lead.hotlead];
    [self setPseudoLeadDescription:lead.description];
    [self setEvent:[EventDAO findEventById:lead.event.idEvent inContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
    if (lead.qrcode.code != nil) {
        [self setQrCode:lead.qrcode.code];
    }
}
```

Looks like the fetch only works once per context or something like that. I'm really lost :(

Comment: So all events should link to the scan, but only one does? Is the relationship 1:many? Are you sure it's the first added and not the last?

Comment: Oops. You were right! The problem was the relationship incorrectly set. My mistake. Thank you!